# Best practice: How do I move controller data out of my service and into my controller?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to learn and follow best practice in my .NETCoreApp. I have read where the repository should not be called from the controller, but should communicate with the service in order to access the repository. Additionally, I know this is bad practice and I want to clean it up.

```
//method in service class:interface
public List<string> Foobar(id)
{
    var data = myRepository.Foobar(id);
    var output = new List<string>();
    foreach (var d in data)
    {
        some code here...
    }
    return output;
}
```

Here is what my controller looks like:

```
public ActionResult Foobar(id)
{
    var objectVM = serviceReference.Foobar(id);
    var output = string.Join("foo",objectVM)
    return File(Endocing.UTF8.GetBytes(output), "filetype", "fileName.xml");
}
```

How do I move that controller logic out of my service class and into my controller?

Comment: That looks generally fine, calling a service that wraps a repository. What do you mean by "move that controller logic out"?

Comment: @NoahStahl The `foreach` and `output` bit

Comment: It sounds like you're doing the best practice already. Typically controllers should have as little code as possible. Most of mine are only 1 line, just calling into a service.